# Error In Build APK Flutter using Android Studios

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I get this error on my terminal I dont know why I can't build my apk:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.

   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

        C:\Users\gaming: AAPT: pc\StudioProjects\alphabeta\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            5.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you check if `ic_launcher.png` is really a png file?

Comment: looks like you have changed the app icon . Choose the one with .png extension